# How locate .cpp Files in a "src directory" using CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am learning c++ and cmake at the moment. I have my source files in the main directory where `CMakeLists.txt` is located. I want to store all source files in a /src directory, but i have no idea how to locate them in CMake.

My CMake File

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(game)

set(GAME_ALL_SOURCES
    main.cpp check.cpp
)

add_executable(game ${GAME_ALL_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(game sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)
```

Anyone a suggestion how to handle it?

best regards

Answer (score 39):

If you want to locate all `.cpp` files in the `src` directory, you could do

```
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)
```

and use `${SOURCES}` wherever you need to. For example:

```
add_executable(game ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: If you need to include all files from all subdirectories, use `GLOB_RECURSE` instead of `GLOB`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
set(GAME_ALL_SOURCES
src/main.cpp src/check.cpp
)
```

Comment: Mhh. This way looks not so comfortable. I look for sth like VPATH in make. I read from the "PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR" Cmake Variable, but i dont know how to use it.

Comment: PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR is not for that purpose. This variable is defined as the location of the last PROJECT() that cmake processed.

Comment: BTW. This answer what I have done for the 5+ years I have used CMake to generate all of my projects.

Comment: Also even if PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR was for that purpose wouldn't it be more painful to write set(GAME_ALL_SOURCES
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/check.cpp
)

Comment: +1 for this solution as it allows you to list and group specific files. If you are on CMake 3.12+, you can make the repeated prepending of the source dir ("_src/_") by using `list(TRANSFORM GAME_ALL_SOURCES PREPEND "src/"`) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55494263/2745495).