# CMake: set directory for target sources

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project where all implementation source files (*.cpp) reside in a *src* directory within the project directory. Some of the files are in further subdirectories. Let's say there are 50 files in *src/foo/*. I need to list these files as part of the `add_library` and/or the `target_sources` function.

Now, everywhere one looks, adding all files from a directory automtically is discouraged, which is fine with me. So I am going to list all the files manually; but repeating the common prefix *src/foo/* 50 times seems really silly and is annoying.

In [the documentation for target_sources](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) it says

> Relative source file paths are interpreted as being relative to the current source directory (i.e. CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR).

So I've added `set(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR "src/foo/")` before the call to `target_source` but it didn't work. (I get a "Cannot find source file" error.)

So what is the correct way to achieve what I want if it is even possible?

N.B.: The (public) header files (*.hpp) of the project are in an *include* directory (outside of *src*). This is nicely configured (without having to list the individual files) with the `target_include_directories` function.

Comment: I think the answer by @Kamil Cuk answers your question. But I wanted to add that setting `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` doesn't work because this is a CMake set variable. Also, the "source" directory according to CMake doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the directory of your source files. This is simply the current directory CMake is processing (i.e. where the current CMakeLists.txt is).

Comment: Regarding the first part, yes you are right, thanks. Also I found that one needs at least CMake 3.13 for the path extension and set `cmake_policy(SET CMP0076 NEW)`. Regarding the second part, this is kind of a pitty. It would be nice (I think) if there were a clear, consistent nomenclature where *SOURCE* always refers to implementation files and *INCLUDE* always to header files.

Comment: It's safe to assume that if a variable starts with `CMAKE_` it's managed by CMake (usually). The usefulness of `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` as opposed to `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` comes in when you are using `add_subdirectory()` in your project and need to know where exactly CMake is currently processing a script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> but repeating the common prefix src/foo/ 50 times

Just prepend the prefix to the sources.

```
set(target_sources
    source1.c
    source2.c
)
list(TRANSFORM target_sources PREPEND "src/foo/")
```

Comment: That works and is quite elegant (imho) even though the "new way" (as some say) of CMake is supposed to get away from (directly) setting variables, to a "property-based" approach.
Also, for CMake beginners reading this, the transformed list is then used as `add_library(MyProj SHARED ${target_sources})`

Comment: Note that `TRANSFORM` is only available starting from CMake 3.12.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `add_subdirectory(src/foo)` and a `CMakeLists.txt` in `src/foo` in which you only have to put

```
target_sources( <your target> PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE
  your
  list
  of
  sources
)
```

I think that would be rather elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` as a relative variable to the old `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is not going to work. If it's set to a value, then it's fair to assume that removing that value and using a custom one will be wrong because you are missing what it was set to before.

You might want to set it as an absolute path, or use `set(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/foo/")`, or do as lots of other people and copy paste the prefix all the time. That's the standard practice (which is also one of the reason I still use GLOB, because I'm lazy), following up on explicit is better than implicit (which is the point of not using `GLOB`).

Comment: Thanks, I did forget to concatenate the additional path to CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR but this was not at the heart of the problem (still did not work).

Comment: See this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73042171)  with solution `list(TRANSFORM SOURCES PREPEND "src/") `after I posted similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I  would have suggested (if you have bash or some similar shell)

```
function prepend() { while read line; do echo "${1}${line}"; done; }
ls *.cc *hh | sort | prepend  "\${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/"
```

then copy and paste :)