# why add_subdirectory() command did not work for my CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake, subdirectory

I have a simple exercise on cmake with following file tree:

```
proj01/
      include/
             functions.h
      src/
         main.cpp
         functions.cpp
         CMakeLists.txt
      CMakeLists.txt        
      README
```

My project CMakeLists.txt is like this:

```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

  project (test01)

  add_subdirectory(src)
  set(SOURCES
       main.cpp
       functions.cpp
   )
    
  add_executable(myProgram ${SOURCES})
```

and when I tried to build, I got error:

```
# Error! 

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:
    main.cpp

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: myProgram
```

If I change the project CMakeLists.txt by giving the absolute path(relative to the project), it worked!

```
#add_subdirectory(src)
set(SOURCES
   src/main.cpp
   src/functions.cpp
)

add_executable(myProgram ${SOURCES})
```

When there is multiple source files in multiple subdirectories, it would be better to explicitly list all source files including their paths as what is done with my working version of the **CMakeLists.txt**.

Spent hours to search for command [add_subdirectories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48509911/cmake-add-subdirectory-vs-include), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934295/add-source-in-a-subdirectory-to-a-cmake-project), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162766/how-to-write-cmakelists-txt-for-a-big-project-with-multiple-subdirectories), but no luck.
The closest one would be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493862/cmake-set-directory-for-target-sources), but there is no solution for that question so far.

What did I miss with my **add_subdirectory(src)** in this simple specific scenario? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: relative paths are always relative to the current cmake file, `add_subdirectory` just processes the cmake file in the sub directory

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, esp. my case? What tripped me is the part `set(SOURCES  src/xxx.cpp` when `add_subdirectory(src)` is already there.

Comment: `add_subdirectory` doesn't seem to do what you think it does, it has no effect on source paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add_subdirectory(src)` results in cmake parsing `src/CMakeLists.txt` creating a new directory `src` in the build tree for building the part of the project in this cmake file.

It doesn't result in you being able to use shorter paths in the `CMakeLists.txt` file containing the `add_subdirectory` command.

If you move the target to `src/CMakeLists.txt` you could use the shorter paths:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project (test01)

add_subdirectory(src) # add src/CMakeLists.txt to this project
```

**src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

set(SOURCES
     main.cpp
     functions.cpp
 )
    
add_executable(myProgram ${SOURCES})
```

---

Personally I'd avoid adding an additional `CMakeLists.txt` file just to shorten the paths. It's easy to remove the duplication of the `src` dir, if that's what you're worried about.

```
set(SOURCES
       main.cpp
       functions.cpp
   )

list(TRANSFORM SOURCES PREPEND "src/")
```

or

```
function(subdir_files VAR DIR FILE1)
    set(FILES)
    foreach(SRC IN ITEMS ${FILE1} ${ARGN})
        list(APPEND FILES ${DIR}/${SRC})
    endforeach()
    set(${VAR} ${FILES} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

subdir_files(SOURCES src
       main.cpp
       functions.cpp
   )
```

Comment: `list(TRANSFORM SOURCES PREPEND "src/")` is exactly what I was looking for, which I have tried with a mistake `${SOURCE}`. The variable name with or without `${}` always confused me at this moment, by the way.  Thanks a lot!